# How to find the integration limits when changing integration order?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I've been dealing with a calculus problem that's driving me insane. I haven't been able to find the integration limits when changing the order of integration from the equation on the left to the equation on the right in

$$\int_0^1\int_0^z\int_0^zf(x,y,z)dxdydz = \int_?^?\int_?^?\int_?^?f(x,y,z)dxdzdy .$$

If anybody has any idea about solving this or a reference on how to solve this equation, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You can find similar questions answered on this site literally dozens of times. You might also find some of my YouTube [lectures](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd) helpful — in particular, days 5 and 6 of Math 3510.

Comment: The change of order of integration that you’re hoping to carry out depends strongly on the shape of the region. If it’s a rectangular block (en français: pavé), there should be no problem. Otherwise, it depends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an integral of this form had been presented to me, I would translate the limits into three (pairs of) inequalities: the outermost is $0\le z\le1$, next is $0\le y\le z$, dependent as you see on the value of $z$, and the third also is $0\le x\le z$.

What happens for a particular $z$? You have the last two inequalities describing a square of side $z$, and it should be that achieving the integration over this square should be independent of the order: $x$ first (innermost) then $y$, or the reverse order. This may depend on the regularity of the function $f$, and I’m not up on details there. If $f$ is just a polynomial in three variables, there should be no difficulty. Hope this helps, as incomplete an answer as it is.